# How do I place Asynchronous Retrofit calls using rxjava. I have to place over a 100 calls asynchronously

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

Here's a sample of the code I've been working on

items contains 100 elements, thus obtaining data using synchronous calling takes up a lot of time. Can someone suggest a way to increase the speed of this operation so that it takes less time.
Currently this takes 15-20 seconds to execute. I'm new to rxjava so please provide a detailed solution to this problem if possible. dataResponses contains RouteDistance objects for each of the 100 items.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<items.size();i++){

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    map2.put("units", "metric");
    map2.put("origin", currentLocation.getLatitude()+","+currentLocation.getLongitude());
    map2.put("destination", items.get(i).getPosition().get(0)+","+items.get(i).getPosition().get(1));
    map2.put("transportMode", "car");
    requests.add(RetrofitClient4_RouteDist.getClient().getRouteDist(map2));
}

Observable.zip(requests,  new Function<Object[], List<RouteDist>>() {
    @Override
    public List<RouteDist> apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
        Log.i("onSubscribe", "apply: " + objects.length);
        List<RouteDist> dataaResponses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object o : objects) {
            dataaResponses.add((RouteDist) o);
        }
        return dataaResponses;
    }
})
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
                new Consumer<List<RouteDist>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<RouteDist> dataaResponses) throws Exception {
                        Log.i("onSubscribe", "YOUR DATA IS HERE: "+dataaResponses.toString());
                        recyclerViewAdapter_profile = new RecyclerViewAdapter_Profile(items,dataaResponses);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter_profile);
                    }
                },

                new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {
                        Log.e("onSubscribe", "Throwable: " + e);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: if rxjava does not help, why do you use it? Cant you just make parallel retrofit calls?

Comment: Excuse me @AlexeiKaigorodov, could you please explain me how your comment is helpful at all? Have you thought about the case, that the issue creater is new to RxJava and does not understand all its Operators in full? If you have another solution how to solve this issue, please provide an answer.

Comment: I mean, placing async calls is one task, and using rxjava for it is quite a different task. This tasks require different questions. I suggest  to first resolve the first task and then ask how to convert working code to rxjava, in hope the second question would not be asked at all because everyting works already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API

```
interface Client {
    Observable<RouteDist> routeDist();
}

final class RouteDist {

}


final class ClientImpl implements Client {
    @Override
    public Observable<RouteDist> routeDist() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            // with this log, you see, that each subscription to an Observable is executed on the ThreadPool
            // Log.e("---------------------", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return new RouteDist();
        });
    }
}
```

Apply threading via subscribeOn

```
final class ClientProxy implements Client {
    private final Client api;
    private final Scheduler scheduler;

    ClientProxy(Client api, Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.api = api;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<RouteDist> routeDist() {
        // apply #subscribeOn in order to move subscribeAcutal call on given Scheduler
        return api.routeDist().subscribeOn(scheduler);
    }
}
```

AndroidTest

```
@Test
public void name() {
    // CachedThreadPool, in order to avoid creating 100-Threads or more. It is always a good idea to use own Schedulers (e.g. Testing)
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10,
            60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<>());

    // wrap real client with Proxy, in order to move the subscribeActual call to the ThreadPool
    Client client = new ClientProxy(new ClientImpl(), Schedulers.from(threadPool));

    List<Observable<RouteDist>> observables = Arrays.asList(client.routeDist(), client.routeDist(), client.routeDist());

    TestObserver<List<RouteDist>> test = Observable.zip(observables, objects -> {
        return Arrays.stream(objects).map(t -> (RouteDist) t).collect(Collectors.toList());
    })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .test();

    test.awaitCount(1);

    // verify that onNext in subscribe is called in Android-EventLoop
    assertThat(test.lastThread()).isEqualTo(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread());
    // verify that 3 calls were made and merged into one List
    test.assertValueAt(0, routeDists -> {
        assertThat(routeDists).hasSize(3);
        return true;
    });
}
```

Further reading:

> http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.de/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html

Note:
It is not recommanded to call an API 100-times concurrently at once. Furthermore when using Zip, this is what will acutally happen, when you have a ThreadPool, which is big enough. When one API-call times-out, an onError will probably emitted for this API-calls. The onError will be propagated further to the subscriber. You will not get any result, even if only on API-call fails. It is recommanded to have some onErrorResumeNext or some other error-handling operator, in order to ensure, that one API-call does not cancel the overall result.